# firebase undefined when working with ReactReduxFirebaseProvider

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, react-redux

Im trying to migrate from react-redux v2 to v3 and start to use the ReactReduxFirebaseProvider. But I don't know why I get:

```
Line 22:  'firebase' is not defined  no-undef
```

**This is my code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createFirestoreInstance, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'


const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore }))
  )
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: fbConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: From what you've shown, the error message is correct - you never defined `firebase`, but you are trying to make use of it.  Did you mean to import a Firebase module here?

Comment: Im not sure, I just followed the guide from here: http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#what-changed. This just how far as I come..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this in your code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```